# how to search a particular string in array in php

Tags: php, arrays

How to get particular string from array, I given example of array as below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Paper:300gsm Silk
    [1] =>  Lamination:Gloss
    [2] =>  Despatch:Standard 5 day
)
```

I need to search if `Despatch` is available in array and if available then get value of it that's after given `:`  and its  `Standard 5 day`

there is not fix sequence in array and also there is not fix string like `Despatch:Standard 5 day` it may be change like `Despatch:Standard 2 day`,`Despatch:Standard 5 day` or may be `Despatch:24 hours`

Comment: Your downvotes are because you've not shown your approach

Comment: Use `array_search` the when you find what you want you break the string. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: in search there is not fix string `Despatch:Standard 5 day` it may be `Despatch:Standard 6 day` or may be `Despatch:24 hours`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, take a look at associative arrays. Then your array looks like this:

```
$myArray
(
    ['Paper'] => 300gsm Silk
    ['Lamination'] =>  Gloss
    ['Despatch'] =>  Standard 5 day
)
```

And you can call it like this then:

```
$value = $myArray['Despatch']
```

Comment: i can not understand associative arrays. :(

Comment: Then you have to use the methods other already told you here. But i can only recommend that you try to learn it, its one of the biggest advantages PHP has to offer and can make your life far more easier. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use [array_walk()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function with callback. Do substring search inside callback

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach and explode

```
foreach ($array as $value) {
   $exp = explode(':', $value);
   if ($exp[0] == 'Despatch') return $exp[1];
}
```

Comment: `explode()`s first parameter is the delimiter

Comment: thanks, just noticed my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you want?

```
$arr = array("Paper:300gsm Silk",
            "Lamination:Gloss",
            "Despatch:Standard 5 day"
            );

$searchword = "Despatch";
$matches = array_filter($arr, function($var) use ($searchword) { return preg_match("/\b$searchword\b/i", $var); });


$res=substr($matches[2],9);
echo $res;
```

Comment: its give `syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION`

Comment: Try this link: http://codepad.viper-7.com/m408ky